# How do I pivot a set of data based on an unknown number of columns in the resultant pivot?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of orders for which I need to produce a report showing totals for each product group, by order.

For example:

```
Order Lines
Line Id, Order No., Product Id, Product  Group Id, Quantity
1      , 1        , 1         , 1                , 5
2      , 1        , 2         , 2                , 3
3      , 2        , 1         , 1                , 5
4      , 3        , 3         , 1                , 1
5      , 3        , 1         , 1                , 5
6      , 4        , 3         , 1                , 4
...
1200   , 999      , 16        , 12               , 4
```

Should show

```
Order No., Group 1, Group 2, ..., Group 12, ..., Group N
1        , 5      , 3,     , ..., 0       , ..., 0
2        , 5      , 0,     , ..., 0       , ..., 0
3        , 6      , 0,     , ..., 0       , ..., 0
4        , 4      , 0,     , ..., 0       , ..., 0
999      , 0      , 0,     , ..., 4       , ..., 0
```

Product groups are defined by the end user, hence I have put in the `...` and `Group N` to signify I don't know how many columns will be in the end result.

The easy bit is grouping the order lines by product group...

```
SELECT OrderNo, ProductGroupId, SUM(Quantity)
FROM OrderLines
GROUP BY OrderNo, ProductGroupId
```

but then, how do I pivot that into the result format, when I don't know how many columns will be in the final `SELECT`?

I'm using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: This descriptions has helped by understanding exactly how to do the dynamic pivoting. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server 
Basically you need to declare all the columns via a '@cols' and then make a SELECT '@query' with all the column names within. After that you just need to EXEC (@query)

Answer (score 0):

With N columns, where N is unknown?
That calls for a Dynamic Sql.

```
DECLARE @DynSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX);

--
-- Calculate the columns
--
SELECT @Cols = CONCAT(@Cols+', ', QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Group ', ProductGroupId)))
FROM OrderLines
GROUP BY ProductGroupId
ORDER BY ProductGroupId;
-- select @Cols as Cols;

--
-- Generate the query string for a pivot
--
SET @DynSql = CONCAT(N'SELECT * ',
N'FROM (',
N'SELECT OrderNo, CONCAT(''Group '', ProductGroupId) AS GroupName, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity ',
N'FROM OrderLines ',
N'GROUP BY OrderNo, ProductGroupId) Src ',
N'PIVOT (SUM(Quantity) FOR GroupName IN (',
@Cols,
N')) Pvt ',
N'ORDER BY OrderNo');
-- select @DynSql as DynSql;

EXEC sp_executesql @DynSql;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/MZZOU71860)

It will show null's.

To show zero's, it's a bit more complicated.

```
--
-- Calculate the columns for the select
--
DECLARE @ColsSelect NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @ColsSelect = CONCAT(@ColsSelect+', '+char(10), 'ISNULL(', QUOTENAME(ProductGroupId), ',0) ', QUOTENAME(CONCAT('Group ', ProductGroupId)))
FROM OrderLines
GROUP BY ProductGroupId
ORDER BY ProductGroupId;
-- select @ColsSelect as ColsSelect;

--
-- Calculate the columns for the pivot
--
DECLARE @ColsPivot NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @ColsPivot = CONCAT(@ColsPivot+', ', QUOTENAME(ProductGroupId))
FROM OrderLines
GROUP BY ProductGroupId
ORDER BY ProductGroupId;
-- select @ColsPivot as ColsPivot;

--
-- Generate the query string
--
DECLARE @DynSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DynSql = CONCAT(N'SELECT OrderNo,', char(10), 
@ColsSelect, char(10),
N'FROM (', char(10),
N'SELECT OrderNo, ProductGroupId, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity ', char(10),
N'FROM OrderLines ', char(10),
N'GROUP BY OrderNo, ProductGroupId) Src ', char(10),
N'PIVOT (SUM(Quantity) FOR ProductGroupId IN (',
@ColsPivot,
N')) Pvt ', char(10),
N'ORDER BY OrderNo');
-- select @DynSql as DynSql;

EXEC sp_executesql @DynSql;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/EWEC99606)

**Result:**

```
OrderNo Group 1 Group 2 Group 12
1       5       3       0
2       5       0       0
3       6       0       0
4       4       0       0
999     0       0       4
```